# How can I update state hook using AsyncStorage data in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I want to update my "images" (in getdata) state using AsyncStorage data. However, when I want to do this, it has an infinite loop. I also do not get the original value in "data". How can I get rid of this?

Here is my code:

setData:

```
const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {

    const storeData = async (imageUri) => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(imageUri)
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('ImageArray', jsonValue)
        } catch (e) {
            // saving error
        }
    }
    storeData(imageUri)

}, [imageUri])
```

getData:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ImageArray')
            // console.log(jsonValue)
            // console.log(JSON.parse(jsonValue))
            // setImages(jsonValue) // if i uncomment this line it's getting infinite loop
            return (JSON.parse(jsonValue));
        } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
        }
    }
    const data = getData() // here in "data" i got {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
}, [])
```

Comment: Please include your `AsyncStorage.setItem` for ImageArray

Comment: Is it okay now? @Hend El-Sahli

Comment: You do not get the data because it is a promise you have to return properly `return await (JSON.parse(jsonValue));`

Comment: For the infinite loop, you might wanna show us where you use "setImageUri", I am acusing useEffect that it's been called many times